# Prove that a continuous function on open sets is continuous on their union.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

I have a function between two metric spaces $f: (X,d_1) \to (Y,d_2)$ such that if $$X=\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$$ for $U_i$ open sets in $X$, $f$ is continuous on each $U_i$.
Prove $f$ is continuous on $X$.

My approach, take a family of open sets $V_i \in Y$ then since $f$ is continuous on each $U_n$ then $$f^{-1} (V_i)$$ is open in $U_i$ for each $i \in \{1,...n\}$.

So $$f^{-1} \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i \right) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n f^{-1} ( V_i)$$
Since all $f^{-1} (V_i)$ are open then their union is also open.

Is this proof correct?
What troubles me is the fact that I didn't use the fact that $U_i$ are open, so this argument could also prove the result even if $U_i$ were not open. So I think I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: open in $U_i$ implies open in $X$, since $U_i$ is open in $X$.

Comment: You *did* use the fact that $U_i$ were open. $f^{-1}(V_i)$ being open in $U_i$ means that $f^{-1}(V_i)=U_i\cap W_i$ for some $W_i$ - open in $X$. However, $U_i$ is also open in $X$ so $U_i\cap W_i$ is open in $X$.